# AHK Script to send two button presses on one button press+release

Tags: autohotkey

Hi im trying to make an AHK Script that sends a button press twice, once when i hold the button down and the second time when i release the button on my keyboard. So far i've only figured out the opposite of making any button a toggle, however that doesn't really help me D: any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $-prefix prevents the hotkey from triggering itself, because it forces the keyboard hook to be used.

```
$a::
    SendInput, a
    KeyWait, a ; wait for the key to be released
    SendInput, a
return
```

For more than one keys, you can use:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SendMode Input
#InstallkeybdHook
#UseHook ; prevents the keys from triggering itself

keys := ["a","b","c","d","1","2","3","4"] ; ....
for each, key in keys
    hotkey, %key%, send_key_twice, on   
return

send_key_twice:
    Send, %A_ThisHotkey%
    KeyWait, %A_ThisHotkey% ; wait for the key to be released
    Send, %A_ThisHotkey%
return
```